# Group sms's from the same number

Tags: android

I'm trying to build my own sms app ( just for learning purposes ) how things work. Now when I receive an sms I save it like this:

```
SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
long time_rcv = currentMessage.getTimestampMillis();

ContentValues smsValues = new ContentValues();
smsValues.put("address", phoneNumber);
smsValues.put("body", message);
smsValues.put("date_sent", time_rcv);
context.getContentResolver().insert(BlacklistConstants.smsInboxUri,smsValues);
```

This works fine except when I want to display the messages:

the ones from the same number are showed separately.

When I retrieve the SMS like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(BlacklistConstants.smsConversations));
Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

I get as output:

```
msg count: 1
thread_id: 0
Snippet: 2

msg count: 1
thread_id: 0
Snippet: 2

msg count: 1
thread_id: 0
Snippet: 2

msg count: 1
thread_id: 0
Snippet: 2
```

Message where like this:

From 100
From 11
From 12
From 12

So actually I should get one with 2 messages in.

Can someone point me out how to solve this?

EDIT:

This is how I get the sms's. The displayConversations is just for seeing:

```
 // Fills the List with Smss
    private void fillSmsList() {
    smsList = new ArrayList<SMSData>();

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(BlacklistConstants.smsInboxUri));
    Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
            SMSData sms = new SMSData();
            sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
            sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
            sms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")).toString());
            sms.setTimeStampReceived(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date_sent")).toString());
            smsList.add(sms);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
}

private void displaySmsConversations() {
    Log.d(TAG,"DisplaySmsConverstations");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(BlacklistConstants.smsConversations));
    Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG,"msg count: " + c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("msg_count"));
            Log.d(TAG,"thread_id: " + c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id"));
            Log.d(TAG,"Snippet: " + c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet"));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concatenate messages from multipart message in `BroadcastReceiver#onReceive` method, like this:

```
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
}

if (messages.length < 0) {
    return;
}

SmsMessage sms = messages[0];
String body = "";
String sender = sms.getOriginatingAddress().toString();

try {
    if (messages.length == 1 || sms.isReplace()) {
        body = sms.getDisplayMessageBody();
    } else {
        StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
        }
        body = bodyText.toString();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}

ContentValues smsValues = new ContentValues();
smsValues.put("address", sender);
smsValues.put("body", body);
smsValues.put("date_sent", time_rcv);
context.getContentResolver().insert(BlacklistConstants.smsInboxUri,smsValues);
```

Comment: Then I still see the messages as being apart. Do I need to edit my query code to get the messages then or? And I don't get why you need the array if you always say the message is on spot 0?

Comment: @user1007522 Is insertion to `BlacklistConstants.smsInboxUri` and reading from `BlacklistConstants.smsConversations` correct? I'm not sure.

Comment: I've edited my question. There you can see how I fill my list. I read there from the inbox. But I think its not appropriate to check there if I already got an sms object with the same number and then append to it. Rigth?

Comment: I think it should work. You should uninstall application or clear app data. Then try to test again.

Comment: When I check the original sms viewer then indeed they are now grouped. So it is my load query that isn't correct.